# Google API Level requirement

Tags: react-native, google-developers-console

Google has required that every app update has to target `API Level 33`. The following image is my application and as you can see, it targets Level 33. and supports API Level 28 - 33.

[image]

Now i am still getting the following message on `Google Developer Console`. Which, in my eyes, does not make sense since the application follows the rules of Google. I have contacted Google Support and they said everything was ok last week but now this message appears.

[image]

Now is my question, am i missing something or is this normal behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behaviour! The error / warning is for some of the older builds in the list that do not follow Googles new rules.